# NGINX returns 301 - Not following WebSocket redirect

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-20.04

I have been in the process of commissioning my new server which is an upgrade of an already existing server. In this process, I have moved from Apache2 to NGINX on Ubuntu 20.04 which interfaces with a Postgres 15 database.

When I start NGINX, I am able to access and log into my web page, however I am unable to load any data (interface constantly trying to load data). Digging through the NGINX log files, I see a `301` error constantly being printed when trying to retrieve device data:

```
123.45.0.67 - - [13/Jun/2023:02:09:41 +0000] "GET /api/ws/plugins/telemetry?token=USER_TOKEN
HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Following some other similar issues on the web, I am fairly certain the root of the issue is with my websocket redirect configuration. My NGINX config's are as follows:

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

**sites-available/website.conf**

```
server {
    if ($host = website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


       listen 80;

       server_name website.com;

       root /var/www/html;
       index index.html;

       #passenger_enabled on;

       location / {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host:8080$request_uri redirect;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location !/\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
#               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

**website-ssl.conf**

```
server {
    include                    /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    listen                      443 ssl;
    server_name                 website.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    root                        /var/www/html ;


    location / {
        proxy_pass                      http://website.com:8080/ ;
        proxy_set_header Host           $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cookie_domain http://website.com:8080/ $host;
        #proxy_cookie_path / /;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /api/ws {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://website.com/api/ws ;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header CLIENT_IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # Other directives specific to your configuration
    # ...

}
```

**sites-available/website-ssl2.conf**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name website.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem;
    #include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api/ws {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
}
```

Comment: 301 is not an error, it's an HTTP redirect status code.  HTTP error codes start with 5xx, common ones such as 500, 502, 503, etc.  You have a 301 defined at the beginning of your website.conf file.  Something meeting the condition of the if statement is probably the reason for the 301.  But why content isn't loading is likely due to something in the page markup (or not in the page markup).  If it's constantly a 301, it's a redirect loop and you should examine your 301 rule.